# How to remove a loaded plugin from dolphindb server?

Tags: database, plugins, reload, dolphindb

I have load a plugin to dolphindb server:

```
loadPlugin("/path_to_PluginMySQL.txt/PluginMySQL.txt")
conn = mysql::connect(`localhost, 3306, `root, `root, `DolphinDB)
```

But now I update this plugin. So I want to reload it or remove the old plugin from server.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reboot the node if your plugin has been updated